# Can i populate /fill a Views exposed filter with a Rules result

Tags: rules, views

I have a group of nodes which are delivery nodes -prices-location-type etc.

I can sort them with a View and exposed filters - 'country' 'type' 'weight' to out put a price - really happy with it so far.

This works great - however I wish to populate the weight field with a value 'calculated weight' calculated in Rules - leaving only the 'country' and 'type' field open to the user.

I have looked for days now and think I have module overload!

Really would be grateful for any insight!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's possible with Rules, though most things are!

But that should be possible with the Computed Field Module. It allows you to do just that, compute fields based on others and you can use it in your views.

https://drupal.org/project/computed_field

Comment: I think I am missing it!

I need to filter the view by a value. i.e once your items are in the cart, the rule calculates the weight, and filters the view to say 'only has term 5kg' this would leave 'country' etc exposed for the user to choose.

Thanks for your earlier reply - If I am missing it could you please explain a little more.Thanks

Comment: You would have computed fields create the value, and then just use a standard drupal filter using that computed field. And leave exposed unchecked so it would not be displayed to them